# saving html source of a webpage in windows phone 8 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

okay i'm trying to save the html of a webpage in windows phone 8 using c#, and all the solution i found on internet doesn't work, is there anyway i can save the contents of html in windows phone 8. Some of the solution i tried which doesn't work

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, targetURL);
//message.Headers.Add(....);
//message.Headers.Add(....);

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //HTTP 200 OK
    var requestResultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
// HttpClient() is not there

HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
myRequest.Method = "GET";

using(WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse() )
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) 
    {
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
// System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? For example with your first approach, using `HttpClient`, doesn't it return `requestResultString`?

Comment: type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx) should help you to reference proper namespace/dlls. Also check [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) for `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use HttpClient in Windows Phone 8, you have to install the NuGet package.  Search for `httpclient`.

[image]

Then you can use

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient myHttp = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
```